# child element replaced with a new element name

Tags: xslt

I'm pretty new to XSLT world. can anyone help me out my question?
    I have an Input XML, and the desired Output XML. Need to write the XSLT for this transformation.
    Condition:
    if any element ends with "11" then the child element node "title" (if exist) then title will be replaced with CDtitle
    i.e,
    cd11/title will be cd11/CDtitle

```
Input XML
---------------
<catalog>
<cd11>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<year>1985</year>
</cd11>
<cd22>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<year>1985</year>
</cd22>
<cd33>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<year>1985</year>
</cd33>
</catalog>


Output XML
---------------
<catalog>
<cd11>
<CDtitle>Empire Burlesque</CDtitle>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<year>1985</year>
</cd11>
<cd22>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<year>1985</year>
</cd22>
<cd33>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>`enter code here`
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<year>1985</year>
</cd33>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want output that is similar to input with some changes, you start with the identity transform and then add to it the customization you desire.

So start with this which copies everything:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then add what you want that is unique in a more specific match. In your case you could state this as "any title whose parent ends with '11'". You could write that this way:

```
 <xsl:template match="title[substring(name(parent::*),string-length(name(parent::*)) - 1, 2) = '11']">
```

Putting it together:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="title[substring(name(parent::*),string-length(name(parent::*)) - 1, 2) = '11']">
            <CDTitle>
                 <xsl:apply-templates />
            </CDTitle>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is:

```
<catalog>
<cd11>
    <CDTitle>Empire Burlesque</CDTitle>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd11>
<cd22>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd22>
<cd33>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd33>
</catalog
```

Answer (score 0):

Below simple XSL will make ur OUPUT as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cd11">
<xsl:copy>
    <CDTitle>
    <xsl:value-of select ="title"/>
    </CDTitle>
        <xsl:copy-of select = "artist"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select = "year"/>
    </xsl:copy>      


</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```